# how say GPS wait for a few minute until return not zero for location

Tags: android, multithreading, gps

This is my code for GPS. and it returns (0,0) as latlng for location. How to wait for few minutes before returning the value not equal (0,0).

this is my code:

```
public class Gps implements LocationListener {
    public static double lon;
    public static double lat;
    Location location;
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        this.location=location;
        lon=location.getLongitude();
        lat=location.getLatitude();
      }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
}
```

and

```
 public String gps() {
        String str_gps=null;
        LocationManager lm = null;
        LocationListener ll = new Gps();
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(G.context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return null;
        }
        boolean gpsEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!gpsEnabled) {
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);
        }
        gpsEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
        str_gps = "(" + Gps.lat + "," + Gps.lon + ")";
        return str_gps;
    }
```

I am thinking of using a thread but not sure where to use it.

Comment: Why not use a callback or listener, or RxJava, or `LiveData`, or an event bus, to deliver you the location when the location becomes available?

Comment: how to use listener?

Comment: See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Location/Classic), which reacts to location changes and shows the weather forecast (note: forecasts probably only work in the US).

Answer (score 0):

this sample code uses timer for checking the valid value for gps. call startRecording() for getting gps

```
private Location getBestLocation() {
    Location mainLocation = null;
    Location gpslocation = getLocationByProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Location networkLocation =
            getLocationByProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    long old = System.currentTimeMillis() - checkInterval * 2;
    boolean gpsIsOld = true;
    boolean networkIsOld = true;


    // if we have only one location available, the choice is easy
    if (gpslocation == null) {
        Log.d("gps", "No GPS Location available.");
        return networkLocation;
    }
    if (networkLocation == null) {
        Log.d("gps", "No Network Location available");
        return gpslocation;
    }
    if (gpslocation.getTime() < old) {

        if (networkLocation.getTime() < old) {
            return null;
        }
        return networkLocation;
    }


    return gpslocation;
}



/**
 * get the last known location from a specific provider (network/gps)
 */
@SuppressWarnings({"ResourceType"})
private Location getLocationByProvider(String provider) {
    Location location = null;

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d("gps", "Cannot acces Provider " + provider);
    }
    return location;
}

//noinspection ResourceType
@SuppressWarnings({"ResourceType"})
public void startRecording() {
    //gpsTimer.cancel();
    gpsTimer = new Timer();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    for (String s : locationManager.getAllProviders()) {
        checkGps = false;
        //startRecording();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(s, updateTime,
                minDistance, new LocationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
                                                int status, Bundle extras) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                        doLocationUpdate(location, true);

                    }
                });
        gps_recorder_running = true;
    }

    /**
     if we want to access ui thread
     */


    // start the gps receiver thread
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Location location = getBestLocation();
            if (location != null) {

                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longtitude = location.getLongitude();
                SharedPreferencesTools.savelatitude(getContext(),
                        getString(R.string.constant_shared_latitude), "" + latitude);
                SharedPreferencesTools.saveLongtitude(getContext(),
                        getString(R.string.constant_shared_longtitude), "" + longtitude);
                Log.i("milliSeconds", "" + date);
                Log.i("location_shared", "" + location);
               // 

            } 
        }
    };

    gpsTimer.schedule(timerTask, checkInterval);
}

public void doLocationUpdate(Location l, boolean force) {
    Log.d("gps", "update received:" + l);
    myLocation = l;
    if (l == null) {
        Log.d("gps", "Empty location");
        if (force)
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Current location not available",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
}
```